# How to persist slot when invoking AWS SDK LexRuntime

Tags: unit-testing, amazon-web-services, testing, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am trying to write a unit test suite for an Amazon Lex chatbot. However, I can only test the first prompt of the conversation. For example:

> User: "I'd like to download a mobile app" -> Response: "Which product do you want to use?"
>   User: "rate watch" -> Response: "Which platform are you using?"

According to `param`'s specification of `PostText` method in [AWS SDK Node.js API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntime.html#postText-property), the only way we can persist information about conversation is by passing sessionAttributes. Even so, I am confused of how to persist `slots` attributes so Amazon Lex can recognize what the next state of conversation is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure I could help explain how to persist slots using LexRuntime if you include the relevant code you are using.